# which mean.js yo sub-generator should I use to created a non-crud app, secured by express-facebook

Tags: node.js, meanjs

Just started using Mean.js boiler plate.
I have an existing node app, which I would like to wrap with mean.js, to have it secured by passport-facebook.

Which yo sub-generator should I use, to add a module (my app), which is not CRUD based, but would have its route (and menu visibility) secured by mean's passport-facebook strategy?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was - 1) using the CRUD subgenerator, 2) modifying the "list" menu item to point to my own (non-crud) html template